# why i can't use lambda for interface at kotlin?

Tags: lambda, kotlin

see, I have a Java class:

```
public final class JavaReceiveSingle {
    public static void useSingle(Single single) {
        single.doSth();
    }
    public static void useSingle2(SingleInterface singleInterface) {
        singleInterface.doSth();
    }
}
```

a Java interface:

```
public interface SingleInterface {
    void doSth();
}
```

a kotlin interface:

```
interface Single {
    fun doSth()
}
```

Now I can use lambda in a kotlin class like:

```
JavaReceiveSingle.useSingle2({})
```

But if I want to do the same thing to kotlin interface:

```
JavaReceiveSingle.useSingle({})
```

IDE will show error :Required: Single!  Found: ()->Unit

And If I specify Single like:

```
JavaReceiveSingle.useSingle(Single{})
```

Still error:Interface Single does not have constructs!

Though the following code works:

```
JavaReceiveSingle.useSingle(object :Single{
    override fun aa() {}
})
```

But why I can't use lambda for a kotlin interface?

Comment: Kotlin has functional types, e. g. `() -> Unit` is a function which accepts no parameters and returns Unit (no value). In that way, there's no need in functional interfaces and SAM-conversions.

Comment: so in that case, functional types is recommended to replace traditional inner anonymous class? if so, then i get the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) is not supported for interfaces defined in Kotlin. There's an issue for that in [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770), but currently I'd recommend using functional types instead of single-method interfaces. If you want them to have a proper name, you may use [type aliases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html), but don't overuse them. In many cases a functional type together with good method/variable names is expressive enough.