# Why do Lambda expressions behave differently for Kotlin and Java classes?

Tags: kotlin

Why can I use Lambda for the class `java.lang.Thread`, but not for `MyThread`?

```
interface MyRunnable{
    fun run()
}

class MyThread(runnable : MyRunnable){    
}

fun test(){
    Thread({})     // All Alright

    MyThread({})   //Exception. Type mismatch <<-- Why ?
}
```

Link to check this example: https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/tbs79qfkh50psp7r3qrdrinrmt/sfkpjq1bjvg4r6d5rmnu6mp4a8

Comment: same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190468

Comment: same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44189319

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs on [SAM conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions):

> Note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported.

In other words, using `{ ... }` syntax is only supported for calls to Java.  The public rationale is that you could do either of:

1. Have your `MyThread` constructor take a first-class function type as a parameter.
2. Use an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions):

   ```
   MyThread(object : MyRunnable {
       override fun run() {}
   })
   ```

This is obviously fairly verbose.  However, according to [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770) Kotlin ticket, the lambda syntax is actually only part of the Java interop, not part of the core language, so would take some careful design to do anything more.

Comment: `MyRunnable` should probably be a functional type + maybe a type alias, avoiding this issue altogether. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323826/why-i-cant-use-lambda-for-interface-at-kotlin/.

Comment: @Oliver if you want to do the +1 that you mentioned, please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770

Comment: @jayson - already done :) (though also, if you're going to edit answers, please do so so the result still makes sense typographically!)

Comment: Sure, trailing * waste bytes!