# Java vs Kotlin interface declaration

Tags: java, interface, kotlin

Say I have this Java and Kotlin interfaces:

```
public interface JavaInterface {

    void onTest();
}

interface KotlinInterface {

    fun onTest()
}
```

Why can't I create an instance of Kotlin interface without constructor?

```
// this is okay
val javaInterface: JavaInterface = JavaInterface {

}

// compile-time exception: interface does not have constructor
val kotlinInterface1: KotlinInterface = KotlinInterface {

}

// this is okay
val kotlinInterface2: KotlinInterface = object : KotlinInterface {
    override fun onTest() {

    }
}
```

Why can't I create an instance of `KotlinInterface` the way I did with `JavaExample` just like the first example?

Comment: It's a variant of this issue, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324821/why-do-lambda-expressions-behave-differently-for-kotlin-and-java-classes

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes sir that seems like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Kotlin has SAM ("single abstract method") only for Java interfaces. It's this way by [design](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-and-sam-interface-with-two-parameters/293/2). There is some info on this on the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) as well:

> Also note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported.

[Related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770)

Comment: I accept the fact that it is not supported. But I can't understand why such feature is unnecessary in Kotlin? It is such a convenient way to create an instance of SAM interfaces.

Comment: @HendraAnggrian Andrey Breslav (kotlin project lead) said: SAM-conversions only work for Java methods, not supported for Kotlin functions, because Kotlin has nice functional types, and there's no need for SAM conversion

Comment: Have a look at this link for some more info https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-and-sam-interface-with-two-parameters/293/2

Comment: I think I might have know why now. Interfaces are easily replaced with Unit in Kotlin. Thanks for helpful links!