# Redundant SAM-constructor can't be remove for Kotlin declared function, but works on Java declared function

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a Java Class function as below

```
public void setPositiveButton(int resId, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
```

I also have the same Kotlin Class function as below

```
fun setPositiveButton(resId: Int, listener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener)
```

When I call them from a Kotlin code

```
    javaClassObj.setPositiveButton(R.string.some_string,
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ -> someFunc()})

    kotlinClassObj.setPositiveButton(R.string.some_string,
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ -> someFunc()})
```

The Java Class function call could be reduced, but not the Kotlin Class function

```
    javaClassObj.setPositiveButton(R.string.some_string,
            { _, _ -> someFunc()})

    kotlinClassObj.setPositiveButton(R.string.some_string,
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ -> someFunc()})
```

Why can't the Kotlin function call reduce the redundant SAM-Constructor as per enabled for Java?

Comment: I'm using Kotlin version 1.1.4-3 on Android.Studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do Lambda expressions behave differently for Kotlin and Java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324821/why-do-lambda-expressions-behave-differently-for-kotlin-and-java-classes)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why would you use SAM in kotlin? while it has native support for functions.

The SAM convention is used in java8 as a workaround not having native function support.

from [kotlin doc#sam-conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions):

> Note that SAM conversions only work for interfaces, not for abstract
>   classes, even if those also have just a single abstract method.
>
> Also, note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin
>   has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into
>   implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore
>   unsupported.

you should then declare a function directly.

```
fun setPositiveButton(resId: Int, listener: (DialogInterface, Int) -> Unit) {
    listener.invoke(
            //DialogInterface, Int
    )
}
```

and then it can be used

```
setPositiveButton(1, { _, _ -> doStuff() })
```

---

In [kotlin 1.4](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/12/what-to-expect-in-kotlin-1-4-and-beyond/) you can use SAM conversions for Kotlin classes.

```
fun interface Listener {
    fun listen()
}

fun addListener(listener: Listener) = a.listen()

fun main() {
    addListener {
        println("Hello!")
    }
}
```

Comment: The (terrible) Android Developers Guide tells people to use SAM. Thanks for explaining why it's bad.

Comment: My guess this is from the days when Java was the only language, and the engineer responsible for converting docs to support kotlin didn't bother to change the code to use the kotlin way and just convert the java code to kotlin. or maybe he creates a script to convert it to automate his job :D

Comment: Why would you use SAM in kotlin? while it has native support for functions.

Because its easier to document a functional interface, its purpose and its function compared to using kotlin's function syntax on the fly.

For example, accepting Compartor interface is much more readable than, taking (T1, T2) -> boolean, because comparator interface's compare method is well documented in its own file.

Answer (score 3):

Extending @humazed answer as compiler complains that

> lambda argument should be moved out of parenthesis

```
setPositiveButton("ok"){_,_ -> doSomething()}
```